# Capture enter event and redirect using jquery

Tags: jquery, redirect, enter

I have a functionality on home page of my site where user enters dish name and presses enter, enter event should be captured and it should redirect to listings page along with dish name as querystring.

I'm using below code, which works only second time when I click enter.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).keypress(function (e) {
                if (e.which == 13) {
                    // enter pressed
                    var searchKeyWord = $("#SearchTextBox").val();
                    window.location.href = "/Listings.aspx?K=" + searchKeyWord;
                }
            });
        });
```

you can see the functionality at http://khanawal.com/home.aspx 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try adding `e.preventDefault();` before the if

Comment: I added it after if...and it worked....thanks @Pete

Comment: hahaha, was just editing this to say after

Comment: first I tried adding it before if...I could not type anything...lol.. :)..anyways did you like my site? its a new startup thing..and very thanks for helping me out...have a wonderful life.

Comment: yeah, very nice. It's made me hungry!

Comment: ha ha ha ha...same here...:)

Answer (score 1):

It appears to work as long as the search box isn't selected.  Try binding to both.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        function handleEnter(e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                // enter pressed
                var searchKeyWord = $("#SearchTextBox").val();
                window.location.href = "/Listings.aspx?K=" + searchKeyWord;
            }
        }

        $(document).keypress(handleEnter);
        $("#SearchTextBox").keypress(handleEnter);

});
```

If that doesn't fix it, there's probably a problem elsewhere in your code.  Search for stopPropagation in your code.